# Find primitive element from a Galois-Field

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

In order to decode a Reed-Solomon RS(255,249) code with the followings parameters:

Primitive polynomial: $$x^8+x^7+x^2+x+1=0$$
Generator polynomial: $$\prod_{i=120}^{125} (x-\alpha^i)$$
I need to find the primitive element (alpha) of GF(256). How can I find it? Is it dependent to the primitive polynomial and the generator polynomial? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean? Is $\alpha$ supposed to be a root of the previous polynomial $f$? $GF(256) = \Bbb{F}_2[t]/(f(t))$ and the root $t$ does have order $255$.

Comment: @reuns Is it obvious that it has order $255$? The roots of two of the irreducible octics are going to have order $17$ and I can't see immediately how one knows which these are.

Comment: No it is not obvious at all, I used http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/ to check it @ancientmathematician

Comment: Thanks. I'd just launched into a hand calculation of the hcf of the given octic and $x^{17}-1$ mod $2$. I think I'll abandon it!

Comment: @ancientmathematician A priori it is not obvious, but it was given that this octic is a *primitive* polynomial, which means exactly that its zeros have order $255$.

Comment: Julien, what reuns said above is the way to go. $\alpha=t+\langle t^8+t^7+t^2+t+1\rangle$ is the desired primitive element of $GF(2)[t]/\langle t^8+t^7+t^2+t+1\rangle$. Unless I made a mistake (typing it into Mathematica) it follows that $\alpha^{120}=1+\alpha^5+\alpha^6+\alpha^7$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. To be more precise, I would like to implement a RS encoder/decoder using a python library. To do so, I need to provide the RS code parameters : [number of redundant bytes = 6, the first root of RS code generator polynomial = 120, the primitive polynomial = 0x187 in binary and the primitive element to generate polynomial roots]. Initially, I took primitive element = 2 by default but different primitive elements provide different redundant byte. Therefore, I wonder how I can find the primitive element based the RS parameters I have.

Comment: Julien, algebraically the meaning of $2$ (=the default primitive element) depends on the choice of the primitive polynomial. This is a common mistake to make unless you have taken a relatively thorough course in abstract algebra (rarely offered to students majoring in telcomm/CS). In the context of representing elements of $GF(2^m)$ as strings of bits, if the defining polynomial is primitive (as is the case here), 0x00...02 (often written just `2`) is then a primitive element. That's what calling the polynomial primitive means

Comment: (cont'd) . And that `2` really (in the language of abstract algebra) really is a shorthand for the element $\alpha=t+\langle f(t)\rangle$ where $f(t)$ is the primitive polynomial defining the field.

Comment: A snag is that converting the field presentation from using one primitive polynomial to another is a pain. For example you get $GF(16)$ from either $x^4+x^3+1$ (or 0x19) or $x^4+x+1$ (or 0x13). Both are primitive polynomials. But the isomorphisms between the two fields are more complicated. There are choices to be made, but the first that occurs to me would take 0x02 (modulo 0x19) to 0x09 (modulo 0x13). Usually it is best to pick one presentation of the field and stick to it. At least when doing Reed-Solomon coding.

Comment: For any $GF(2^8)$, there are 128 primitive elements, any of which can be used for Reed Solomon, and as you noted, each will produce a different set of redundant bytes for the same data message, but that won't interfere with a Reed Solomon implementation. 16 of the 30 possible $GF(2^8)$, including 0x187, can use 2 as a primitive element, and those cases, 2 is what is normally used.